# Environment variables not changing in Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, environment-variables

1. `set NODE_ENV=production` not working in my pc. `NODE_ENV` is not changing from "development"

   ```
   if(app.get('env') === 'development'){
       app.use(morgan('tiny'));
       console.log("Morgan enabled...");
   }
   ```
2. `set PORT=5000` not working - `PORT` is not changing from "3000".

   ```
   const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
   ```

Comment: What OS? How do you run your script?

Comment: please add an example of how do you run the app, with the envs

Comment: are you make folder .env and install dotenv and make config

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai this doesn't answer the question and isn't the only way to set up environmental variables

Comment: Describe how you set the environment variables, exactly. For example, if you run node in one console window, and set the variable in another window, this can never work. That's not a node issue. How are you trying to set the variable values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Windows user, I had problems in the past with exporting / setting environment variables for node to use.

I ended up using the [`dotenv` NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) since you can be sure it correctly loads the environment variables regardless of what system you are developing on.

> Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env.

First, install and save it:

```
npm i dotenv
```

Create a file in the root of your project called `.env`

```
PORT=5000
```

You can set any number of variables using simple `X=Y` syntax.

Then, somewhere in your code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

// my main application code
```

With the above example, you now have access to `process.env.PORT` which will equal `5000` (value set from the `.env` file)

**Note:** Avoid storing `.env` in your version control by adding a `.gitignore` rule:

```
node_modules/

# Other ignore rules...

# Add this line
.env
```

Good luck!

Comment: What kind of problems with setting environment variables did you have?

Comment: I cannot exactly recall as I have been using this `dotenv` solution for months now. Part of the problem for me was setting a variable before calling an NPM command. The other problem was that the project involved another developer on a Linux system and we didn't want to maintain two of every command: one for linux and one for windows. So we implemented this solution.

Answer (score -1):

you should be installed dotenv by `yarn add dotenv`  then make file to in the folder .env
in the server or the main page for app add this code

```
const dotenv=require('dotenv').config({path:'./env})
```

//this depand where are you store the .env  and the name file for path
and in the file .env make variable
PORT=3000